# Powering 5V IC with 3.8V

Tags: voltage, atmel, esp8266, input

I'm trying to power a ESP8266 and ATMega128 from a LiPo battery via the TP4056 charging module. I get 3.8V out of the charging module. According to the ATMega128 Datasheet it is possible to power the IC with

> Operating voltage 2.7 - 5.5V

so my question is which output voltage from the I/O pins will I get.

Comment: What does the data sheeet tell you about IO logic levels versus supply voltages?

Comment: In which chapter can I find this?

Comment: @Ribisl search for the electrical specifications; there is always a table telling you exactly this kind of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your battery voltage is 3.8V then you will get 0/3.8V logic levels from the ATMega128. This voltage is perfectly fine for ATmegas, the only limitation may be maximum clock speed (check it in the datasheet).

Answer (score 1):

You will get around 3.8 itself for logic high. You can't get more than that anyway. Anything between 2.7 V and 3.8 V will be considered as logic high in your digital pins.